# Elasticsearch - How to find out what is the type of a particular index

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I created a document in ES. Later I want to query it, but I forget the type, therefore I can not complete the command. However I still remember the the index name.

How do I retrieve the type name of the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index name, you can quickly retrieve all the mapping types in your index using the following command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index_name/_mapping?pretty'
```

You'll get a response like the one below:

```
{
    "index_name": {
        "mappings": {
            "type_name": {          <----- this is the type name you're looking for
                "properties": {
                   ...field definitions...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```